# A/B test to validate revenue uptick

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

This is a question regarding an A/B Test that we are running in my department. We are doing dynamic pricing of a product using Machine learning and doing an A/B test to compare with the current mode of rule based/static pricing.

The hope is that the dynamic pricing using Machine learning will product an uptick in Revenue.

- Control - will sell the Product at fixed set of price points (Mostly Rule based slab pricing)
- Test - Will sell the same product at dynamic Price (Dynamic Pricing using Machine Learning)

A sample of how the products could be sold is below.

[image]

Which test would be apt to check if our solution (Test) indeed provided revenue improvement or not?

Comment: I feel some information is missing here... Probably you could share data sample to understand better. Is the "control" only one price associated to a given product?

Comment: Sure, I will share a sample data for better understanding. The "control" is not one price always, that also changes but the changes are based on some written rules. The machine learning that we are doing challenge those written rules and claims to being more intelligent.

Comment: @Pitouille - Added sample data

Comment: Seeing the data, I think quantity sold is an important parameter here. For instance, on the 02 Jan, average of Test for product A is the same as control... but if you sold only 1 product at 80$ and 10 at 120$ the conclusions will be completely different.

Comment: The test is being run for 3 months. So would comparing mean prices of test vs control make sense?

Comment: Sorry, I know I am asking only questions... but I think it is more complex than what it seems. So, is your analysis just about the robustness of your algorithm or do you want to determine its efficiency over time period and product, etc...? To understand better what is going on with your algorithm, I will perform first an analysis over one product only (because margins are comparable) and determine the benefits (difference between product cost and sold price) for each sale.  Then it will be easier compare Control benefits vs Test benefits.

Comment: @sharathnatraj What is the randomization unit in your experiment? In other words, are you splitting the users who will see prices generated from different pricing scheme over all products depending on which group the users are in; or are you splitting the products which how their price will change depends on whether they are in control/treatment, but every user will see the same price once set for the day/hour/minute; or something else? The stats test required is different in each case.

Comment: @sharathnatraj Furthermore, what is your experiment's success criteria in terms of a concrete metric/evaluation criteria? Increasing ASP (average selling price) is good generally, except in the case where the total number of sales drops.

Comment: @B.Liu - The POC is successfull if our solution can bring significant uptick in revenue. We basically control the prices based on several features. The rule based which is existing currently is pretty legacy. So our solution should ideally generate better revenue.  There is legal issue in showing same price for two users at the same time. So the test is designed in a way that, on a certain set of dates, users will see our price and for other set of dates, users will see the old prices. I know that this brings some skewness and is not ideal but thats the best we could do.

Comment: @Pitouille - We are testing this few products. If the test shows that our solution is generating better revenue in the test time frame for all the products, then we would like to extend to other products. So the question is, per product, how we do we know which solution generated better revenues, then how can we make a statement across all products?

Comment: @sharathnatraj Ah yes, good 'ol switchback experiments. [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.00148.pdf) might help, but it is on the theoretical side. A way to test if the new algorithm improves to simulate how the total revenue (which is the product of # sales and ASP - the former can be modelled as a named distribution and the latter can be bootstrapped) could vary in both groups, and compare the distributions of the simulated total revenue samples. (Not an answer as I did not think this though 100%).

Comment: @sharathnatraj Please consider updating your question with the clarifications you have provided - comments might be deleted without notice.

Comment: @B.Liu what about performing a product by product Welch's t-test (if requirements are met) in the first place?  Comparing the revenue (difference selling price vs cost price) for each sale in order to obtain 2 samples: Control and Test... and provide general overview before going further.